# Set border symbology by bordering feature?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, borders

I'm using a US state shapefile, and I want to have different border types based on properties specific to the border, not to any state.

For example, I might want the Florida-Georgia border to be red, the Florida-Alabama border to be blue, the Florida-ocean border to be non-existent, and the Alabama-Georgia border to be dotted.

Is there any way to accomplish this in QGIS or ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

I think @PolyGeo is almost there, except I would use [Polygon to Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Polygon_To_Line/00170000003t000000/).

With this tool you can set to *Identify Neighbors* which will allow you to join to the polygons by left id and right id. Add a field called Left_State and Right_State then join by left and calculate the state into the Left_State and do the same for the Right_State. This will allow you to locate the Alabama-Georgia border (also Georgia-Alabama) and all the other 50+ states to uniquely symbolize how you feel is appropriate.

From memory, where there is no bordering polygon (Florida-Ocean) the ID is -1 to say that there's no polygon there... perhaps just delete these lines if you're not going to show them.

Comment: You're right - the availability of the IDENTIFY_NEIGHBORS option makes Polygon to Line a better choice than Feature to Line against the requirements of the Question as I read them too.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention the **ArcGIS for Desktop** version or license level which is available to you so I have assumed ArcGIS 10.2 and Advanced.

That configuration will give you access to the **[Feature To Line (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000039000000)** tool which:

> Creates a feature class containing lines generated by converting
>   polygon boundaries to lines, or splitting line, polygon, or both
>   features at their intersections.

With state borders available as line features you are free to symbolise them as you wish.